# Counter while using Pandas dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I  want update the column counter to counter + 1 every time in encounters the string [hr]. My column named "Counter" would ideally look like 11111,22222,33333 .... 999999 s=

This is

My code is below

```
df['Counter'] = df['elapsed time'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x != "[hr]" else 2)
```

I try with the below but get the error SyntaxError: lambda cannot contain assignment

Is there a way around this?

```
df['Counter'] = df['elapsed time'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x != "[hr]" else x =+ 1)
```

Example dataframe

```
      elapsed time distance travelled significant wave height  total  Counter
0             [hr]               [nm]                            [m]        2
1            0.000              0.000                          1.035        1
2            3.000              0.000                          0.000        1
3            6.000              0.000                          0.000        1
4            9.000              0.000                          0.000        1
...            ...                ...                            ...      ...
76774      320.638           4181.591                          0.000        1
76775      321.000           4186.698                          0.000        1
76776      322.116           4202.445                          0.000        1
76777      323.181           4217.467                          0.000        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want count next values after `[hr]` value then compare values forst and then use cumulative sum:

```
df['Counter'] = df['elapsed time'].eq("[hr]").cumsum()
```